# Arcgis JS api WMS layer on top of basemap

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms

I'm trying to place WMSlayer on top of basemap "streets", but have ran into problems. Code:

```
// mapHandler.mapextent = new esri.geometry.Extent(350000,6370000,750000,6630000,new esri.SpatialReference({"wkid":3301}));

mapHandler.map = new esri.Map('map', {
// extent: mapHandler.mapextent,
center: [25.88270117, 58.70311058],
basemap: 'streets',
spatialReference: new esri.SpatialReference(4326),
zoom: mapHandler.defaultZoom
});
mapHandler.wms1layer1info = new esri.layers.WMSLayerInfo({title:"Maa-ameti fotokaart"});
mapHandler.wms1resourceinfo = {extent: new esri.geometry.Extent(300000,6300000,800000,6700000,{wkid:3301}),layerInfos:[mapHandler.wms1layer1info],version:["1.1.1"]};
mapHandler.wms1layer1 = new esri.layers.WMSLayer("http://kaart.maaamet.ee/wms/fotokaart?",{resourceInfo:mapHandler.wms1resourceinfo,visibleLayers:["MA-FOTOKAART"]});
mapHandler.wms1layer1.setImageFormat("jpg");
// mapHandler.wms1layer1.setVisibleLayers(["0", "1", "2"]);
mapHandler.wms1layer1.setImageTransparency(false);
mapHandler.map.addLayers([mapHandler.wms1layer1]);
```

With the above code only the basemap is displaying. I'm getting the following warning in console:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.ogc.se_xml: "http://kaart.maaamet.ee/wms/fotokaart?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=ima…=2445863.801486572,7992358.782554072,3272606.6994188153,8240626.2504242575".
```

If I comment out:

```
basemap: 'streets',
```

Will result in WMSlayer displaying correctly and also prints the following the console:

```
Map: Geometry (wkid: 4326) cannot be converted to spatial reference of the map (wkid: 3301)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set basemap 'street' in Map parameters, the Map spatialreference will be fixed to WebMercator(10200). So, your wms service must get map images as WebMercator instead of 3011. But, I guess your wms service not supports projecting map images.